# Affordable trainers for winter conditioning

Tags: training, winter

I've just bought a 2018 Specialized diverge with 30mm tires. I'd like to purchase an affordable and efficient trainer that won't cost me too many bananas. Any recommendations? I've perused amazon and there are some best sellers with decent reviews but I can't seem to see if they'll accommodate my tire size size.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your question as asked will get close votes as specific product recomendations are off topic here. You can re-write it as 'what should I look for in an affordable trainer...'

Answer (score 2):

All trainers are adjustable and will work with a wide range or tire sizes and wheel diameters.

Efficiency isn't a concern with trainer because their function is actually to be completely *inefficient* i.e. to make you do work, soak up your energy output and turn it into heat. Low noise, adjustability, and  'feel' are what you are looking for.

If you want affordable, look on Craiglist or an equivalent bike and gear used marketplace where you located. Where I am there seems to be many to choose from. People buy them, don't get into indoor training then look to sell them on.

Make sure you get a trainer than is compatible with your rear wheel, attachment - quick release or through axle. Be aware than cheaper trainers that clamp onto the quick release skewer can chew it up, so consider getting a cheap or used sacrificial one.

Comment: Also be aware that trainers where the rear wheel presses against a roller tend to 'eat' up the tyre quite fast. It's OK with intermittent use For prolonged use they are best used together with a trainer specific rear tyre that is harder and abrasion resistant but must not be used on a road.

Comment: @Carel its very much dependant on the roller/tyre combination as to whether they get 'eaten' or not.  I've had an old vittoria rubino on my trainer wheel for 1000's of KM and its barely more worn than when put it on.